# How to solve the issue of my following statement: "The project crashes when the memory reaches 4 gb"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, memory, active-directory

I am working on a project which imports data from the Active Directory to put backup data in a SQL Database. In the Active Directory I have a large amount of data which causes crashing my application because the memory reaches more than 4 gb at run time.

Has someone expreienced/faced a problem like this? And how can I solve it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @W.Ghaz.For Visual Studio crashes when the memory reaches 4 gb,it may be memory used too large at run time. you could try the following methods to make Visual Studio reduce memory.1.Periodically delete your .sdf and .suo files(while Visual Studio is closed)so they can be recreated (instead of deleting,consider just renaming in case you want them back,as you may loose some configuration settings).

Comment: 2.You can right-click and select Unload Project to unload project from large solutions with [solution folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/kz8aa2es(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). 3.You could try to run two different Visual Studio instances: the first has the large solution loaded but is not used to debug(Debug>Start without Debugging),and the second has no solution loaded but is attached to the running process for debugging.

Comment: 4.If you are loading a lot of symbols(you can count "Symbols loaded" in the VS Output window), you can [disable this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/x54fht41(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#to-specify-a-directory-where-symbol-files-are-located) with Tools>Options>Debugging>Symbols:"Load only specified modules",then click "Specify included modules" and uncheck "Always load symbols located next to modules".You can load additional symbols while debugging with Debug > Windows > Modules.

Comment: @HuiLiu-MFST Thank you for your answers! The problem is: what I am trying to solve is when running the project and it handles more than 4 gb the project crashes, so it is not something what could be solve in Visual Studio as compiler itself.

What I am looking for is a way which makes it able to me to free the unneeded memory at run time.

Comment: @W.Ghaz.For the majority of the objects that your project creates,you could refer to the .NET [garbage collector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/induced) to handle memory management.When virtual memory is running out of space,when allocated memory is suppressed acceptable threshold and when we call [GC.Collect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=net-5.0) method explicitly GC will be triggered.(as GC runs continuously,we actually do not need to call this method)

Comment: When you create objects that include unmanaged resources,you could explicitly release those resources when you finish using them.You could use the [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) explicitly to free memory used by unmanaged resources(fonts,bitmaps,database connections,and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by changing the Target Platform in the project properties to 64 bit.

To change the target platform go to **Project** on the menu bar -> **{your project name} Properties** -> **Build** -> **Target Platform** -> choose x64.

References:

1. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/81de7e68-bfd3-4b1c-b64e-8c5444e359e9/how-do-i-set-visual-studio-2019-to-64-bit?forum=visualstudiogeneral
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-platforms?view=vs-2019
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-modify-the-target-framework-and-platform-toolset?view=msvc-160